# How to extract same word from a paragraph

Tags: vb.net

I want to extract same word from a paragraph. My paragraph is in richtextbox1 and the words to be extracted are given in an array. My code is as below:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim A(1) As Char
        A(0) = " "
        A(1) = ","
        Dim B As String = RichTextBox1.Text
        Dim x As String() = Nothing
        Dim F As Array = {"SMUGGLING", "CROSSING", "INFILTRATION"}
        x = B.Split(A)

        For Each F In x
            Label1.Text += F.Contains(x) & ControlChars.NewLine
        Next


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got your for each loop mixed up a bit.

With the below code, having the F.contains here, will output as either true or false in the label rather than the word itself.

```
 Label1.Text += F.Contains(x) & ControlChars.NewLine
```

I don't think F.contains will work while using an array, as .Contains is not a member of System.Array.

I would consider using generic lists instead.

Here is an example I have made using generic lists instead.

```
Dim A(1) As Char
A(0) = CChar(" ")
A(1) = CChar(",")
Dim B As String = RichTextBox1.Text
Dim x As String() = Nothing
Dim F As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
F.Add("SMUGGLING")
F.Add("CROSSING")
F.Add("INFILTRATION")
x = B.Split(A)

For Each word In x
    If F.Contains(UCase(word)) Then
        Label1.Text += word & ControlChars.NewLine
    End If
Next
```

I have reworded your for each loop so that the the F.contains is an If statement and then adds it to the label if it returns true. Also in the for each loop you don't really want to be using for every F in x as it doesnt make sense and you are already using F. So i changed it to for each word in x.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem. If this answered the question, Can you mark as answered thanks :)